# Prove $g(0)=0$ and $g'(0)=0$, where $g(1/n)= 0$ for all natural numbers $n$

Tags: real-analysis, derivatives

My question is: Suppose that $g:\Bbb R →\Bbb R$ is differentiable at $x=0$ and for each natural number $n$, $g(1/n)=0$. Prove that $g(0)=0$ and $g′(0)=0$

I know this is a duplicate question but the original did not fully solve it and that is where I am stuck, proving $g'(0)=0$ I can easily prove $g(0)=0$ by $g(0)=g(\lim_{n\to \infty} \frac1n)= \lim_{n\to \infty} g(\frac1n)=0$

I really don't understand how looking at $\lim_{h\to 0} {g(h-0)-g(0)\over h}$ is supposed to help, which is what was suggested. If someone could help me solve this it would be much appreciated, thank you.

Comment: What if $\lim_{h\to 0} \frac{g(0+h)-g(0)}{h}=\lim_{n\in\mathbb{N}}\frac{g(0+\frac{1}{n})-g(0)}{\frac{1}{n}}$?
Anyway, why could you state that $g(0)=\lim_{n\in\mathbb{N}} g(\frac{1}{n})$?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You showed $g(0) = 0,$ and we know $g'(0)$ exists. This means

$$\lim_{h\to 0}\frac{g(h)-g(0)}{h-0}= \lim_{h\to 0}\frac{g(h)}{h} = g'(0).$$

One particular route to $0$ for $h$ is along the sequence $1/n, n=1,2,\dots$ Thus

$$\lim_{n\to \infty}\frac{g(1/n)}{1/n} = g'(0).$$

Since each $g(1/n)$ is given to be $0,$ and $\lim 0 =0,$ we have $g'(0)=0.$

Answer (score 0):

The fact that $f(0)=0$ follows from continuity. We need to show the limit $\lim_{h\rightarrow 0}\frac{f(h)-f(0)}{h}$.

This is true because the sequence lemma holds; for the sequence $x_{n}=\frac{1}{n}\rightarrow 0$, we have $\lim_{x_{n}\rightarrow 0}\frac{f(x_{n})-f(0)}{x_{n}}=0$, hence $f'(0)=\lim_{x_{n}\rightarrow 0}\frac{f(x_{n})-f(0)}{x_{n}}=0$.